# Confused about Rails has_and_belongs_to_many Association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, associations, has-and-belongs-to-many

I have two models, items and categories which have a many-to-many relationship using the has_and_belongs_to_many association.

In my models I have

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_and_belongs_to_many :categories
end
```

and

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_and_belongs_to_many :items
end
```

I created a join table "categories_items":

```
create_table "categories_items", :id => false, :force => true do |t|
    t.integer "category_id"
    t.integer "item_id"
end
```

I'm not getting any errors, but I'm just a bit confused about exactly what the association allows.  Right now, if I have some category @category, I can find all the Items in it by doing

```
@category.items
```

I assumed that I could find the categories associated with a given Item @item by doing

```
@item.categories
```

However I get an error that says 
    ActiveModel::MissingAttributeError: missing attribute: category

Am I misunderstanding how a has_and_belongs_to_many association functions, or am I missing something in my code?  Thank you!

Edit - Additional Information:

I think the confusion lies in how I'm supposed to assign items/categories.  Currently, I'm creating them independently:

```
@item = Item.new
... add attributes ... 
@item.save
```

and

```
@category = Category.new
... add attributes ... 
@category.save
```

and then associating them with

```
@category.items << @item
@item.categories << @category
```

Comment: What you have here looks ok, and the association *should* work both ways. How is `@item` being assigned?

Comment: I just pasted your code into a test project (Rails 3.2.1) and the association worked fine for me both ways.

Comment: Usually the MissingAttribute exception is thrown when you do a Model.select("something").first.somethingelse. Can you paste in a git the code you're running and the backtrace?

Comment: x1a4 - I edited my post to include information about how I'm assigning `@item` and `@category`, I think that's probably where I'm going wrong.

Comment: @steffi2392 only one of those assignments should be necessary. Because it's a two-way association, setting one should take care of the other. Also see what @bcd said, about this exception often coming from use of `select` to limit the number of columns returned. That's almost always the cause of this in the times I've seen it.

Comment: I've just create a new rails app with your setup and it works as expected: https://github.com/cristianbica/so-10574844. See code from console here: http://pastebin.com/qG263r1Q (as x1a4 said you should only add one way or else you'll get duplicates)

Comment: Thanks everyone!  bcd and x1a4 you were right - my association was working, the limited 'select' was causing me problems.  If one of you wants to post that as the answer I'll mark it.  And thanks for pointing out that I didn't need to add it twice!

Answer (score 0):

I think I've experienced what you're going through once before. I believe the confusion is in how to connect through other tables. In the following, one user can have many skills. A skill is also connected to many users. Something similar to this may work for you ^_^

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :skills_users
  has_many :skills, through: :skills_users

class SkillsUser < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :skill

class Skill < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :skills_users
  has_many :users, through: :skills_users
```